# Jquery is attached, but gives Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I don't understand this. As far as I know, Uncaught TypeError comes when the jQUery is not linked to the page and the script makes use of JQuery functions. Wordpress header attaches it by default but still i'm getting this error. I'm looking for the reason for this, not the solution.

[image]

Comment: Use `jQuery` instead of `$` in wordpress

Comment: I was looking for the reason rather than the solution.

Comment: $ is the operator used in many JavaScript libraries so it conflicts with jquery library and WordPress is no exception. So it is always advised to use 'jQuery' instead of $ especially in WordPress and magento.

Comment: Plus there are jquery version conflicts occur as well so there is jquery migrate library used for this or particular jquery version added in wp_footer in functions.php and $.noConflict is also used.